# What does the 1 stand for in command names like bat(1) git(1) on man pages

Tags: linux

When reading man pages I often see the command name followed by a `(1)`.
`bat` in particular has made the point of making their headline `A cat(1) clone with syntax highlighting and Git integration.`

I wonder what the `(1)` means? And if is there a circumstance it could be another number?

Comment: Not really a programming question hence a comment. 1 is historical, because the chapter 1 of Unix manuals was dedicated to user commands, chapter 2 to system calls, chapter 3 to library, etc. So this is nothing more than the classification in the manual.

Comment: you can get the separate sections specified by the numbers with man -e and so man -e 5 crontab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manual pages are organised by section. To see the entire list, try `man man`. Here is a snippet.

```
   1   Executable programs or shell commands
   2   System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
   3   Library calls (functions within program libraries)
   4   Special files (usually found in /dev)
   5   File formats and conventions eg /etc/passwd
   6   Games
   7   Miscellaneous (including macro packages and conventions), e.g. man(7), groff(7)
   8   System administration commands (usually only for root)
   9   Kernel routines [Non standard]
```

Something like `printf` might have entries in multiple sections of the man pages. Here is an example

```
% man -k '^printf$'
printf (1)           - format and print data
printf (3)           - formatted output conversion
```

You can see that there are two manual pages for `printf` - one in section `1` and the other in section `3`. The short hand representation for "printf in section 1 of the man pages" is `printf(1)`. You can request this specific page by doing `man 1 printf` or do `man -a printf` to get all the pages one after another.

Answer (score 1):

Do `man man` and you will be enlightened.
The numbers you mention refer to the section of the whole of the manual pages.

From `man man`:

The table below shows the section numbers of the manual followed by the types of pages they contain.

```
   1   Executable programs or shell commands
   2   System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
   3   Library calls (functions within program libraries)
   4   Special files (usually found in /dev)
   5   File formats and conventions eg /etc/passwd
   6   Games
   7   Miscellaneous (including macro packages and conventions), e.g. man(7), groff(7)
   8   System administration commands (usually only for root)
   9   Kernel routines [Non standard]
```

Comment: This is effectively a link-only answer. You could quote in the relevant segment from `man man`.